# Recursively grep through epub files

Tags: grep, search, recursive, epub

I tried the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127458/how-can-i-run-a-grep-on-epub-mobi-files), but without luck.

```
find . -name "*.epub" -exec zipgrep pattern {} \;
```

showed me "matched", but didn't give me the matching epub file back. Also, it returned huge blobs of data, which were hard to grep through.

`grep -a` didn't work at all.

I want something like `grep -R` but for epub files.

Comment: I think `zipgrep` should pass other command line options to `egrep`, so did you try adding `-H` (or `-l` if you want only the matching filename)?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the full path to all the *.epub files.

```
find / -name *.epub -exec ls {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

If you want to store that ouput in a list:

```
find / -name *.epub -exec ls {} \; 2>/dev/null >> /tmp/list
```

If you want to search that list for a string I would use a for loop. If you are getting huge blobs of data it may see them as one long line. this will print the patter and the 5 char before and after.

```
for i in `cat /tmp/list` ; do echo $i ; grep -a -o -p '.{0,5}pattern.{0,5}' ; done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats a super useful combination of commands. However, the first one just doesn't give me anything back? (I have a lot of epub files in that folder/subfolder).

Comment: Which distro are you using? This works with RHEL6.

`$ find /tmp -name *.epub -exec ls {} \; 2>/dev/null
/tmp/test/subdir/sub.epub
/tmp/test/subdir/subdir2/sub2.epub
/tmp/test/test2.epub
/tmp/test.epub`

Comment: You do not need `-exec ls`, this is the default behaviour of `find`.

Comment: @SpruceTips: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I ran the same command (just replaced the / with a . )

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
find . -name '*.epub'  -exec zipgrep -q {pattern} {} \; -print
```

- `-q` suppresses the display of hits
- since `zipgrep` returns 0 only if it finds a match, the `-exec zipgrep ...` acts as a filter, so the `-print` is only executed if there was a match (in case you need it, it can be another `-exec` that will only be executed on the matching files).

Comment: I get quite some errors when running the command: caution: filename not matched:  OEBPS/images/[Originaldateien]/
caution: filename not matched:  OEBPS/images/[Originaldateien]/929-4-8300-2179-8_img_cover.jpg
caution: filename not matched:  OEBPS/images/[Originaldateien]/logo.bmp
zipinfo:  cannot find or open ./new_ebooks/Harry, Fontaine - Final Chapter Three.epub, ./new_ebooks/Harry, Fontaine - Final Chapter Three.epub.zip or ./new_ebooks/Harry, Fontaine - Final Chapter Three.epub.ZIP.
/usr/bin/zipgrep: 97: test: -eq: unexpected operator
/usr/bin/zipgrep: 100: test: Illegal number: